# Как сделать чтобы после каждого GET запроса "адресная строка" очищалась

Tags: php, html, javascript, get

Как сделать чтобы после каждого GET запроса обработчик очищал "адресную строку" от get параметров?

Comment: сделать редирект на нужный урл? а сами данные запроса передать в куках.

Comment: Может стоит использовать POST?

Comment: @Олег Б 
а как пост будет работать?

Comment: Так-же как и GET, только данные из POST "не видны" в адресной строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постарайтесь лучше придерживаться паттерна ["PRG" (`Post/Redirect/Get`)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Никакого смысла в нем нет. Теперь уже нет

Comment: Высказались. Альтернативу предложить не забыли?

Comment: @rnddev: Вы делаете довольно категоричное высказывание. Потрудитесь уж аргументировать, а?